# How to assign DataContext from parent View's ViewModel (Property)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

EDIT:
Here is a small sample Solution (VS 2013) showing my exact problem: nakkvarr.net/TestApp.zip

I have two views:

- MainView
- EmployeeView

I want my EmployeeView to reference the MainViewModel property "employees".
I tried this:

```
    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding DataContext.MainViewModel,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type EmployeeLisViewModel}}}">
```

But all I get is the Error: EmployeeListViewModel ist not supported in WPF ?!
(EmployeeListViewModel is also the name of the property of my MainViewModel)

The thing is: 
My MainView has some menu items. One is for sorting the employee list, which is inside my UserControl. My UserControl ViewModel contains the Commands for sorting.

EDIT:
I changed it to vm:EmployeeListViewModel ... now the error is gone...but now I don't seem to get access to the ViewModel :/

```
<ia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadEmployeesCommand}"
```

Does not trigger, no emplyees get loaded. When I use the ViewModel directly, it works just fine.

```
MainWindow.xaml
    <Window x:Class="de.XXX.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:de.XXX.Views"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:de.XXX.ViewModel"
            Icon="/Images/App.ico"
            Style="{StaticResource MainWindowStyle}"
            Title="MainWindow">
        <DockPanel  DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                ...
            </Menu>
            <controls:EmployeeListView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" DataContext="{Binding EmployeeListViewModel}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Window>

EmployeeListView.xaml //not model, copy & paste error x_X
<UserControl x:Class="de.XXX.Views.EmployeeListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:de.XXX.ViewModel"
             xmlns:ia="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="350">
    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type vm:EmployeeListViewModel}}}">

        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="EmployeeList" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" />

    <ia:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ia:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadEmployeesCommand}" />
        </ia:EventTrigger>
    </ia:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I used a field, changed it to a property and change the code to: AncestorType={x:Type MainViewModel.EmployeeListViewModel}}} ... still the same error :/

Comment: can you please post at least the relevant parts of the xaml for your views? I'm a little confused by your attempt to find an ancestor in xaml that's not a control, but a viewmodel.

Comment: I added the XAML of the two Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your SubControl to below, this should work.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.SubVM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

I have a hint on what you are trying to achieve and I guess you have missed some details on Binding especially on other underlying properties needed to be set. This part is working based on the given code. But then, there are numerous ways in making it better. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, the code compiles, but the message inside my SubControl doesn't show up. I think puttin a ViewModel inside another and sharing it with a UserControl is not a good way to do this.

Comment: All I want to do is to access some method from my UserControl from My MainWindow (Like calling a Command to sort my List inside the UserControl).

Comment: @DoubleVoid it did to me. Make sure of "SubVM" is typed correctly.

Comment: Okay thanks, I had a typo. And some other problems. WPF seems to be rather unforgiving x_X But now it's working. Maybe I should take a look into DependencyProperties anyway. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a combination of misunderstandings here! Your UserControl has

`x:Class="de.XXX.Views.EmployeeListView"`

defined as the class name in xaml. However, you're also saying that the file is named EmployeeListView*Model*.xaml? A .xaml file should never be named a viewmodel. I believe you should have MainWindow.xaml, EmployeeListView.xaml, MainWindowViewModel.cs, and EmployeeListViewModel.cs, is this the case?

Also, in your MainWindow.xaml, you're already setting the datacontext of your EmployeeListView usercontrol:

```
 <controls:EmployeeListView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" DataContext="{Binding EmployeeListViewModel}" />
```

This implies to me that your class structure is that MainViewModel contains an instance of the EmployeeListViewModel... is this true?

If all the above is true, then this part of your UserControl xaml does not make sense:

```
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type vm:EmployeeListViewModel}}}">
```

Whether EmployeeListViewModel is actually your *view* and not your *viewmodel*, the property "MainViewModel" does not exist on EmployeeListViewModel, so the binding will never work.

If you're trying to have a reference to your Window's DataContext, MainViewModel, within your UserControl, a possible way to do this is:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<controls:EmployeeListView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

This should set the DataContext of your EmployeeListView to MainViewModel. Then, in your EmployeeListView, you can do this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="de.XXX.Views.EmployeeListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:de.XXX.ViewModel"
             xmlns:ia="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="350">
    <DockPanel
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="EmployeeList" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" />

    <ia:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ia:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EmployeeListViewModel.LoadEmployeesCommand}" />
        </ia:EventTrigger>
    </ia:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

There's a lot of assumptions about your views and viewmodels I made for this answer. I hope this at least helps. If it doesn't make any sense, please post your viewmodels as well :)

Comment: I just read your answer, thanks. No, my Views are named like "EmployeeListView". The DataContext assignment was a left over from a test. Before I try to explain too much, I created a small Project, that shows my exact problem: http://nakkvarr.net/TestApp.zip :)